# flutter: Speech recognition failed: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel plugin.csdcorp.com/speech_to_text)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, speech-to-text

When integrating Flutter as a module into an existing native application, I may encounter issues with Flutter plugins, especially when dealing with platform-specific initialization. In my case, the speech_to_text plugin is causing a runtime error during initialization on iOS.

> flutter: Speech recognition failed: MissingPluginException(No
> implementation found for method initialize on channel
> plugin.csdcorp.com/speech_to_text)

Code: (AppDelegate.swift)

```
func crateEngineFlutter(){
        self.flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "package", project: nil)
        self.flutterEngine?.run(withEntrypoint: nil)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine!)
}
```